# Maximo - Set value in MeterReading based on inbound values of METERDATA

Tags: javascript, integration, jython, maximo

We use Maximo 7.6. We have a requirement in Integration. We are receiving METERDATA thorugh interface (MXLoader).. It adds data in METERREADING, LOCMETERREADING and MEASUREMENT tables (OOB functionality). Now Our Requirement is, based on inbound values from METERDATA table, METERREADING, LOCMETERREADING table values should be set. We checked the Object structure processing class - MaxMeterDataProcess and MeterReading, MeterData Mbo classes.  We could not find where these values are set..  Has any one worked on a similar requirement? Kindly provide your valuable suggestion....

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you looked at MxLoader?

Comment: MxLoader is working fine. Tables are updated, But I need to set a field value based on condition..

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing an Automation Script with Object-Save-Add-BeforeSave Launch Points on METERREADING and LOCMETERREADING that check for whether they are owned by a METERDATA.

Comment: Tried MeterReading Object Launch point add/Update Before save, After save etc. It is not triggering

Comment: Try naming your script METERREADING.NEW.